# How not to "fill up" a view when flagging

Tags: views, flags

I have a list of different tasks (about 100 items). Each time a user logs in, he should get a display of 5 tasks randomly selected out of this list. When he finished the task, he can flag them as "done" and the task will disappear from the list. I managed to do this with [flag module](https://drupal.org/project/flag) and [views module](https://drupal.org/project/views).
The problem is, that the task-list is much longer than the 5 tasks. So each time the user flags a task with "done" this task will disappear from the list, but a new task will show up at the same time.
How can I stopp a view to be "filled up" in order that the user can empty his task list? (And may be gets new tasks only the next da or on next login).

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please put more details about your implementation. How do you filter per-user list, for example? What logic would you want to implement? If it's about design decisions, it might be off-topic here. Be as clear about what you want as possible. Not "this or that or something" - decide what exactly you want before you will ask us how to get it, please :)

Comment: It is not about design: My view displays all tasks created by admin. I have implemented a rule, that all new saved tasks are flagged as not-done by current-login user after login. In the view there is a filter that it shows only not-done tasks from the current user (it is not a global flag). So if a users clicks on "done" (the flagging link) from an item in the view, the item disappears from the view display. This works fine, but I do not want that the view is "filled up", at the same moment, that means that the next item from the list is shown up in the view.

Comment: The additional features you request to keep track of "done" tasks and alter the number displayed accordingly is probably beyond what can be done by configuring Views and Flags through the GUI. You need to write a custom module.

Comment: @FreeRadical and even if it's doable via gui (I could bet it it, to be honest - not a *good* idea, but probably *doable*), it is a feature to be designed and implemented - in my opinion too broad task for Q&A format, especially given that OP does not even know for sure when he wants to reset that track.

Comment: Yes as others have suggested, you will need to write some custom code. Basically I'd imaging it would be a Views Field handler that executes some task and refresh the View via Ajax?

Comment: Have you investigated the https://drupal.org/project/views_flag_refresh module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to manage the problem without the need to write new code. I am posting it here, so that it may help others as well, even if the topic is very specific.

How to manage, that a view doesn't fill up immediately after flagging:

1. Create a "helper flag" and set the flag link to the helper flag on the nodes of your view.
2. Create a rule, that the flagging of the helper flag, adds the action of unflagging your original flag.
3. Put the filter in your view in this way, that not only all nodes are displayed that are unflagged with your original flag, but also those with the helper flag (or-filter)
4. Create a rules display of this view.
5. Create a rule that reacts on the event "user has logged out".
6. Add a view loop from the created rules display and add the action (unflag the nodes". choose the "helper flag" to be unflagged.

That's all. As long as the user stays logged-in, the view is not filled up, when he flags the nodes. As soon as he logs out, the helper flag is unflagged and the view is filled up.